# Using the twilio notify api, is it possible to insert unique tracking links to each message?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I currently do a foreach loop and send each text on a list individually. It takes a while to get through the whole list, so I'm looking at the notify api.

All users on a list receive the same message, each containing a link to access content. the only difference between the messages is that the link contains a parameter in the url (?abc=unique_value). Does anyone have any idea on how I would be able to insert the unique link for each message, using the notify api? I'm currently using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Notify is useful when each outbound message is identical. Your first approach of calling the [/Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource) resource for each message is the correct approach if each message has some type of unique data.

Comment: yeah I figured! just wondered if anyone knew anything that I might of missed, like maybe there was an undocumented way of passing substituion data. Thanks though!